# Spring mvc portlet: how to get data from jsp?

Tags: java, spring, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a problem, how can I send my data from html form in jsp (portlet) to controller? 
Here some code

Portlet JSP

```
<form id="smsSender" method="post" action="${sendSmsUrl}">    
<input type="text" name="phoneSuffix" maxlength="7"/>
<textarea id="message" maxlength="70" name="message"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<portlet:actionURL name="sendSms" var="sendSmsUrl">
</portlet:actionURL>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class SmsController extends MVCPortlet {

@ActionMapping
public void sendSms(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
        String message = ParamUtil.get(request, "message", "");        
    }
}
```

Please, help me understand how to do it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: What version of liferay are you using?

Comment: liferay 6.2 @ParkashKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be because of qualified parameters for portlet:

Possible solution are:

i. Use aui html tags.

```
<aui:form id="smsSender" method="post" action="${sendSmsUrl}">    
    <aui:input type="text" name="phoneSuffix" maxlength="7" />
    <aui:input type="textarea" id="message" maxlength="70" name="message" />
    <br />
    <aui:button type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

OR

ii. Add `<portlet:namespace />` to the field(s) name attribute:

```
<textarea id="<portlet:namespace />message" 
    maxlength="70" name="<portlet:namespace />message"></textarea>
```

OR

iii. Add `<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>` in 
liferay-portlet.xml

Comment: I am pleased to help you.